# Using Multiple Database Connections To Access Repositories and Entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

We have a Main database with multiple tables.   we are going to have an unknown amount of 'duplicate' databases depending on the client currently being used.

this was setup like the following

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
      School_A:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: 'mysql://nibbr:nibbr@127.0.0.1:3306/School_A'
      School_B:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: 'mysql://nibbr:nibbr@127.0.0.1:3306/School_B'
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: default
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        mappings:
          App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
      4bf40159870dc1b23c97e7906a303f39:
        connection: School_A
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        mappings:
          App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
      46f0618dadff645591073709906f006c:
        connection: School_B
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        mappings:
          App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src'
            prefix: 'App'
```

now the Databases exist,

migrations using

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=46f0618dadff645591073709906f006c
```

worked perfectly fine.

but i cannot switch to specific EntityManagers to manipulate the correct database. it always uses the Default.

I know this has been touched on alot but no real answers have been given

each database uses all the same Entities and repositories.  all i want to change is which database symfony 4 uses.

```
 $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,'46f0618dadff645591073709906f006c');
```

when i persist a new entry though $rep, no matter what value gets passed it only uses the first entity manager and connection it comes across in the doctrine.yaml.  unless i pass a string that isnt an EntityManager name, then i get a 500 error.

using ANY variation of ->getManager() causes 500 error too. im fairly new to symfony

thank you kindly

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. You should remove default entity manager and code a system on your application to select the entityManager to use. We need more information on "which is the correct database". (For example: each user has got his own database, User selects a year and there is a database for each years, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. ill do my best to give more information.   This works from a command application. the user will pass 3 arguments.  one of the arguments comes in as a school hash, datatype ( which entity student / parent ) so when its being processed, `$em->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,$this->schoolHash); `  is used in a controller to select the database             the school hash decides the database of which to use

Comment: you can use $em->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,'School_A'); for school A and  $em->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,'School_B'); for school B .....

Comment: I removed the default settings, and now its just choosing School_A everytime. Even Adding    `$em->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,'School_B')` still returns School_A

Comment: try $em->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,'46f0618dadff645591073709906f006c'); if it return School_B

Comment: ill give that a go thank you. could be summit getting lost maybe?

Comment: EntityManager::getRepository only takes one argument.  I have no idea what @abderrahimesanadi is trying to tell you.  You will need some upstream code to determine which entity manager is being used for a particular request.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this still returns as it always  does.  just seems to outright ignore the setting. if i put something random in i get 500 error, so its definitly seeing it and again, migrations work just fine.

Comment: sorry its `getDoctrine()->getRepository(SchoolStudent::class,$this->schoolHash)` it does take 2 arguments but yeah $em-getRep does only take one thats my mistake

Comment: Doctrine is not ignoring anything.  It is working as designed.  In your question you have "--em=School_A" which makes no sense since School_A is the name of the connection, not the name of the entity manager.  Take a break then come back and try to analyze exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: that was the origional way round i have the names, it was changed after that, another mistake of mine.

Comment: so if its not ignoring it, but is only ever using the default or first option rather, then what is it im missing?

Comment: $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('4bf40159870dc1b23c97e7906a303f39') might help but at this point there does not seem to be any relation between the code you posted and your actual question.  Be aware that there is an edit button under the left corner of your question.  Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use two different managers that way (in services with dependency injection):

In this example i inject the repository directly into the service constructor.

```
<service id="my_service_id" class="FQCN">
    <argument type="service">
        <service class="Doctrine\ORM\DocumentRepository">
            <factory service="doctrine.orm.46f0618dadff645591073709906f006c_entity_manager" method="getRepository"/>
            <argument>Namespace\SchoolStudent</argument>
        </service>
    </argument>
</service>
```